# Outlook Add-In can't be installed on a machine after installing Office 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, office-interop, outlook-addin, office-2013

I have implemented an Outlook add in visual studio 2010 using Outlook Add in template and VSTO, I created an install for it using MSI installer (created in visual studio 2010).. I am able to install it on all the machines (x86 and x64).

Recently I tried to install the same exact installer on a machine which has Office 2013 installed on it and getting the following error:

[image]

I should emphasize that I haven't changed anything in the system configuration and just installed Office 2013 in addition to what was installed there.

I ran the MSI in "Lv" mode (logging with verbose) and log file doesn't give me helpful information. All it contains is :

```
=== Logging stopped: 15/02/2013  14:22:04 ===
MSI (c) (20:24) [14:22:04:626]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (c) (20:24) [14:22:04:626]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (20:24) [14:22:04:626]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (20:24) [14:22:04:626]: Product:  Outlook AddIn -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (20:24) [14:22:04:626]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Outlook AddIn. Product Version: 1.7.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: "Company". Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (c) (20:24) [14:22:04:626]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (20:24) [14:22:04:626]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (20:24) [14:22:04:641]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 15/02/2013  14:22:04 ===
```

Thanks for help in advance...

Comment: You may get more info logging with all params `lvoicewarmupx`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually add-in installers also [package PIA prerequisites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx), to install when missing. That is why the message says to run "setup.exe" instead of the MSI directly.

The prerequisites install before the main package, i.e. the MSI, and this is handled only by the "setup.exe" file.

If the project is configured for Office 2013 too than VS should have included the appropriate prerequisites in the package and running setup.exe should install them. Try that and see how it goes.